# jQuery: How to combine two lines of code (with same target)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to jQuery and am trying to **combine the following two lines of code** as they both target the same div ( `$(this).closest('div.col-9').nextAll('div.hiddenDiv')` ) and I have other, similar scenarios where this would reduce code as well:

```
$(this).closest('div.col-9').nextAll('div.hiddenDiv').find('input, select, textarea').removeProp('checked').removeProp('selected').not(':button, :checkbox, :hidden, :radio, :reset, :submit').val('');
$(this).closest('div.col-9').nextAll('div.hiddenDiv').hide();
```

It works fine the way it is written above so I am probably combining it the wrong way.
**I tried both the following but they both fail:**

```
$(this).closest('div.col-9').nextAll('div.hiddenDiv').find('input, select, textarea').removeProp('checked').removeProp('selected').not(':button, :checkbox, :hidden, :radio, :reset, :submit').val('').end().hide();

$(this).closest('div.col-9').nextAll('div.hiddenDiv').find('input, select, textarea').removeProp('checked').removeProp('selected').not(':button, :checkbox, :hidden, :radio, :reset, :submit').val('').hide();
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the `$.fn.hide()` method first then find children and preform required operation.

```
$(this)
    .closest('div.col-9')
    .nextAll('div.hiddenDiv')
    .hide()  //<=-----------------------   Call Hide method
    .find('input, select, textarea')
    .removeProp('checked')
    .removeProp('selected')
    .not(':button, :checkbox, :hidden, :radio, :reset, :submit')
    .val('');
```